# How should the WSO2 API Manager process be managed and kept alive in production?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Wso2 has a .sh file to start it the API manager. Although the documentation is quite thorough it doesn’t specify how the wso2 process should be started and kept alive in an environment.

Would a system service (system.d) be the recommended approach or is there another and more appropriate way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Linux you can use below command to start the server which will keep the process running in the background.

```
sh wso2server.sh start
```

Hope bellow document will help to understand the product startup options.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Product+Startup+Options

If you are looking for an option which allows starting the JVM automatically during machine restart kind of situation, the solution will be OS dependent. For example, in Linux, you can start the server as a Linux service using init.d script as explained in below document.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Installing+as+a+Linux+Service

Comment: What I am looking for is a resilient way to start it I mean, something that survives machine restarts and that if the process dies restarts it automatically.

Comment: This depends on the OS. For example, in Linux, you can start the server as a Linux service using init.d script as explained in below document. https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Installing+as+a+Linux+Service

Comment: Updated the answer with the above option.